# How to handle an array of inner subscriptions with rxjs without nested subscriptions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, subscription

I have prepared [this example on Stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-tf72bt.stackblitz.io) for my question. In this Angular app, I have a `NestedSolutionComponent` with my current working solution and an `AppComponent`, where I want to achieve the same result by using proper rxjs operations.

For a real world example which is a bit more complex, I am looking for a solution to map the results of my multiple inner subscription to an array of my outer subscription.

A REST call for a user service provides me this array:

```js
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'User One',
      groupIds: [1, 3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'User Two',
      groupIds: [2, 3, 4]
    },
  ]
```

And for each group, I would like to call a REST group service that is providing me further infos about the user group. All in all, I call the group service 5 times, each ID in the group array gets called once. When finished, the result should be mapped into the groups array - but instead of solely having the ID, the whole object should be stored into the array.

The solution should look like this:

```js
  [
    {
      id: 1
      name: 'User One'
      groups: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Group One' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Group Three' }
      ] 
    },
    {
      id: 2
      name: 'User Two'
      groups: [
        { id: 2, name: 'Group Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Group Three' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Group Four' }
      ] 
    }
  ]
```

By nesting subscription, the solution is easy - but ugly. I call the user service first, then calling for each user each groups:

```js
    this.appService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      const _usersWithGroupNames = users.map((user) => {
        const userWithGroupNames = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          groups: [],
        } as UserWithGroupNames;
        user.groupIds.forEach((groupId) => {
          this.appService.getGroupById(groupId).subscribe((groupWithName) => {
            userWithGroupNames.groups.push({
              id: groupWithName.id,
              name: groupWithName.name,
            });
          });
        });
        return userWithGroupNames;
      });
      this.usersWithGroupNames.next(_usersWithGroupNames); // Subject
    });
```

I have spent hours and hours but I really do not see any solution with proper rxjs operators. I tried `switchMap` and `mergeMap`but ended in a hell of nested map operations. Also `forkJoin` seems not to help me out here, since I receive an array and I have to call the inner subscriptions in a certain order. When I call multiple mergeMaps in a pipe, I cannot access the previous values. I would like to have a solution like that

```js
// not real code, just dummy code
userService.pipe(
  xmap(users => generateUsersWithEmptyGroupArray()),
  ymap(users => users.groups.forEach(group => groupService.getGroup(group)),
  zmap((user, groups) => mapUserWithGroups(user, groups)) // get single user with all group information
).subscribe(usersWithGroups => this.subject.next(usersWithGroups))
```

Anybody here who knows a proper and readable solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach** : Used [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap), [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap), [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from), [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)

```
this.appService
  .getUsers()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((users) =>
        // for each user
      from(users).pipe(
       // merge map to run parallel for each user
        mergeMap(({ groupIds, ...user }) =>
        // wait to retrive all group details of current user at mergeMap
        // after completing use map to map user with retrived group 
          forkJoin(
            groupIds.map((id) => this.appService.getGroupById(id))
          ).pipe(map((groups) => ({ ...user, groups })))
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h8vu3q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the above code, `forkJoin` will wait to get all `groupIds` details for a particular user, and also if he has retrieved group id 3 for the first user it will again retrieve `groupId` 3 details for user 2 and so on. In short duplicate group, details will be retrieved.

**Second approach** : Below is the approach we will get all `groupsIds` out of the user array, make them unique, get all details of them in parallel, and at the end, we will map group details to users by their `groupIds`, Here we will not wait for each user group id details to retrieve and also duplicate group details will not be retrieved.

```
this.appService
.getUsers()
.pipe(
    switchMap((users) =>
      // get all unique groupIds of all users
      from(this.extractUniqueGroupIds(users)).pipe(
        // parallell fetch all group details
        mergeMap((groupId) => this.appService.getGroupById(groupId)),
        // wait to to complete all requests and generate array out of it
        reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val], []),
        // to check retrived group details
        // tap((groups) => console.log('groups retrived: ', groups)),
        // map retrived group details back to users
        map((groups) => this.mapGroupToUsers(users, groups))
      )
    )
)
.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // this.usersWithGroupNames.next(result);
});

private mapGroupToUsers(users: User[], groups: Group[]): UserWithGroup[] {
    return users.map(({ groupIds, ...user }) => ({
        ...user,
        groups: groupIds.map((id) => groups.find((g) => g.id === id)),
    }));
}

private extractUniqueGroupIds(users: User[]): number[] {
    const set = users.reduce((acc, { groupIds }) => {
        groupIds.forEach((id) => acc.add(id));
            return acc;
    }, new Set<number>());

    return [...set];
}

interface UserWithGroup {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  groups: any[];
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p5ernk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried, but this is how I would structure this stream. It's a `switchMap` *(Which could be a `mergeMap` or `concatMap` instead, it shouldn't matter in this case)*, a `forkJoin` *(Not sure why it didn't work for you, but it should from what I've seen)*, and a `map` to create the final user with group names.

If you have any questions, I'll be happy to update this answer with some clarifications.

```ts
interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  groupIds: number[]
}

interface UserWithGroupNames {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  groups: any[]
}

class ArbiratryClassName {

  public usersWithGroupNames$: Observable<UserWithGroupNames[]>;

  embellishUser(user: User): Observable<UserWithGroupNames> {

    // forkJoin to get all group names
    return forkJoin(
      user.groupIds.map(groupId => 
        this.appService.getGroupById(groupId)
      )
    ).pipe(
      // map to create final UserWithGroupNames
      map(groups => ({
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        groups
      }) as UserWithGroupNames)
    );
    
  }

  arbiratryInit(): void {

    // instead of this.usersWithGroupNames Subject, create
    // the stream directly as usersWithGroupNames$, and subscribe to
    // usersWithGroupNames$ whereever you'd use the subject.

    this.usersWithGroupNames$ = this.appService.getUsers().pipe(

      switchMap((users: User[]) => 
        forkJoin(users.map(u => this.embellishUser(u)))
      )

    );
  }
}
```